# Is it possible to learn martial arts only by myself?

Tags: judo

I have great interest in martial arts, especially in judo technique. I really want to learn it but there is no such training institute . Is it possible to learn it from book and video lectures or some sort of virtual training?  I am really looking forward to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there's no local schools,  your best bet is either finding someone local who has done any decent amount of judo, or, finding a school or instructor in a related grappling art.  Any form of wrestling will give some related tools.

Part of this is that grappling is about manuevering other people's bodies and manuevering your own around what they're doing - you can't really learn that alone.  The other part is that a lot of manuevers or actions can be trained safely, or unsafely, and having someone who has already done a grappling art will allow you to learn how to do that, instead of risking yourself or your partners going in blind.

Once you have some basis and people to train with, then you can really make use of videos - if you already have a good feel for balance, locks, etc. you can start to practice new ones you don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but in the same way you can learn to play violin by yourself, or learn a language by yourself. If you do not have a teacher who can comment on (aka critique your progress and give specific advice) it will be a challenge.

Comment: But I just want to ask you some ways to start with, any basic level book or videos to follow?

Comment: My background is Zen Buddhism. Many people think they can practice zen without a teacher and only from books. Maybe people can, but without a guide many people will wonder around for a long time. Without a guide you must be vigilant to stay on the path. Training in an art without a teacher can be like applying makeup without a mirror. It may feel right from your perspective, but sometimes you need another person to tell you that you missed a spot. :)

Comment: I understood your point.

Comment: I do not know any good books. I practice Japanese karatedo. Maybe find another style that is available in your area? At least then you will learn some fundamentals that can transend all arts and give you a community of practioniers.